# Is filtering on a for each noticeably more performant than if clauses within the loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I am working on a code base with a lot of `ForEach... If's`. I was planning to convert them to filtered for each's but I wanted to know is the speed improvement worth the time. I know all of these things are relative but if the filtered for each is magnitudes faster in general it would make sense to change.

```
 For Each egg In chicken.Where(Function(x) x.Tasty = True)
      ' Do Stuff
 Next

 For Each egg In chicken
      If x.Tasty = True Then
           ' Do Stuff
      End If
 Next
```

Comment: The only way to answer this is to time it **for your specific scenario**. Micro-optimisations are scenario-specific. Frankly, though, **either way**, this is unlikely to be the thing that changes the shape of your app's performance. Now: what makes you think this is a performance problem *in the first place* ?

Comment: @MarcGravell There is a huge amount of redundancy going on in the code. The app runs on low powered machines. I thought it might be an idea to remove this redundancy and in the process this came up. To change them is not a massive deal so I wanted to see if it helps. Granted it is not going to be a major impact but small acorns add up I suppose was my thinking on this.

Comment: Measure. The only way to focus your dev time on useful performance changes (rather than changes that make you feel better, but don't change the performance) is to measure.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of it that way... Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is use the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class to measure how long each `For` loop takes e.g.

```
Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
sw.Start()

' Do some work..
sw.Stop()

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time to do some work: {0}", sw.Elapsed.ToString())
```

Comment: I accepted this as that is essentially what marc was saying above.